# How to add active class dynamically using react bootstrap pagination.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an items api which is working fine and I added the active `className` on `Pagination.Item` but its not working. I'm not sure if I missed something else to make it work.

See docs for pagination [react-bootstrap.github.io](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/pagination/)

Below is my code and also here is the sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-active-class-react-bootstrap-eqrhhu).

**Movielist.js**

```js
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Col, Card, Row, Pagination } from "react-bootstrap";
import MovieListPagination from "./MovieListPagination";

const MovieList = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  // Default current pages and posts
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(4);
  // Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = items.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
  // Change page
  const paginate = (pageNumber) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
          //console.log(result.results);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div className="p-3">Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div className="p-3">Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <Row className="justify-content-center">
          {currentPosts.map((item) => (
            <Col sm={6} lg={4} xl={3} className="py-3" key={item.id}>
              <Card bg="dark" text="light" className="text-center h-100">
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{item.title}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>{item.body}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          ))}
          <Pagination className="justify-content-center">
            <MovieListPagination
              postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
              totalPosts={items.length}
              paginate={paginate}
            />
          </Pagination>
        </Row>
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default MovieList;
```

**MovielistPagination.js**

```js
import { React } from "react";
import { Pagination } from "react-bootstrap";

const MovieListPagination = ({
  currentPage,
  postsPerPage,
  totalPosts,
  paginate
}) => {
  const pageNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Pagination.First />
      <Pagination.Prev />
      {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
        <Pagination.Item
          key={number}
          className={`${currentPage === number ? "active" : ""}`}
          onClick={() => {
            paginate(number);
          }}
        >
          {number}
        </Pagination.Item>
      ))}
      <Pagination.Next />
      <Pagination.Last />
      {/* {item.alt_description ? item.alt_description : item.user.name + ' Collection'} */}
    </>
  );
};

export default MovieListPagination;
```

Comment: <MovieListPagination
              postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
              totalPosts={items.length}
              paginate={paginate}
              currentPage={currentPage} // add this 
            />

Comment: Oh my.....Yeah i forgot that! thx.:)

Answer (score 1):

Pass `currentPage` to the Component

```
<MovieListPagination
  currentPage={currentPage}     // You missed this line
  postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
  totalPosts={items.length}
  paginate={paginate}
/>
```

Comment: Oh my.....Yeah i forgot that! thx.:)

Answer (score 0):

In this component, you take the "currentPage" prop, but don't pass that prop when using the component. At the time of using the component, you must pass props like this:

```
`<MovieListPagination
     currentPage={currentPage}     <<
     postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
     totalPosts={items.length}
     paginate={paginate} 
  />`
```

Also, even if you pass this prop, you won't see the class because you're using validation incorrectly. I'm assuming you want to use type checking. If you want to use type checking, you must typecheck

> className={``${typeof currentPage === "number" ? "active" : ""}`}

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to pass `currentPage` prop to `MovieListPagination` component

```
    <MovieListPagination
  currentPage={currentPage}     // add this line
  postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
  totalPosts={items.length}
  paginate={paginate}
/>
```